React Native Webview
I am having issues injecting an object into react native Webview. injectedJavascriptObject returns undefined using window.ReactNativeWebView.injectedObjectJson().
How can I achieve injecting an object using injectedJavascript instead?
injectedJavaScriptObject={{customvalue: "Hello world"}}
Returns undefined
